# mongodb findAndModify (upsert) insert field if document does not exist but don't update field if document being updated

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I want to use `findAndModify` (**upsert**) to modify a document. I want to do:

- The document must contain a field `created_at`;
- If a new document is being inserted, **create** this field
- However, if existing document is being inserted, **don't** **update** `created_at`.

I use `findAndModify` as follows which will update `created_at` on every `upsert` which is not what I want.

```
  var acctsCollection = "accounts";
  account.created_at = new Date();
  account.newData = newData;
  var newUpdate = {
    $set : account
  };
  var options = {
    upsert  :true,
    new: true, 
  };
  collectionDriver.findAndModify(acctsCollection, query, newUpdate, options);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [$setOnInsert](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/setOnInsert/#up._S_setOnInsert):

```
var newUpdate = {
    $set : {newData: newData},
    $setOnInsert: {created_at: new Date()}
};
```